# Header property is not working in UWP CustomTextBox

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

In UWP I have created CustomTextBox which is derived from TextBox control. In my CustomTextBox, I have used various properties but some properties are working and some are not working.

Below properties are working fine,

- Width Height BorderBrush, etc,.

Below properties are not working,

- Header Text, etc,. Please find code snippet on below,

**MyTextBox.cs**

```
public sealed class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyTextBox);
    }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SfMaskedEdit_header">

    <Style TargetType="local:MyTextBox" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyTextBox">
                    <Border
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="SfMaskedEdit_header.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SfMaskedEdit_header"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid x:Name="grid1">

        <local:MyTextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="Hello" Header="MyTextBox" Width="200" Height="40" 
                         BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" Background="Pink"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Please use the below sample for further information,

**Sample:** [MyTextBox](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsISs7GoFbYYgrxpZX4QY3Acka7ZkA?e=KEQDXJ)

Comment: Hi, We notice that you have the same post on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/1ae3f2e5-1f89-4213-a4f6-36778d049e24/), my colleague has already replied to you there, you can continue to track your question on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/1ae3f2e5-1f89-4213-a4f6-36778d049e24/), thanks.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the information. Now, it is working fine as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you have overridden the default template and hence removed all the elements that normally make up a `TextBox`.

To understand this, it is important to make it clear that UWP controls usually just provide a *behavior*, but are themselves made up of multiple other controls in their template (the terminology is usually that XAML controls are *look-less* by default). And these controls are providing the visual representation of the control. For example, in the case of `TextBox`, the template is made up of `Border` for the borders around it, `TextBlock` for the placeholder text, `Button` for clearing out the content, a `ScrollViewer` where the `Text` input is rendered and a `ContentPresenter` for the header and so on.

Your custom `TextBox` is in fact just the `Border` itself, which means you have essentially *lost* the capabilities you mentioned because there are no controls to *surface* them visually.

To fix your problem, I suggest **starting with the default `TextBox` template** (by copying and pasting it to your own style. And then just editing the parts that you want to change. This way you will start from the fully functional state and can decide what to change while retaining the capabilities of the control.

You can find the **default template** in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\{version}\Generic\generic.xaml`. You can search for `<Style TargetType="TextBox">` to find the default `TextBox` style and template.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. Is there any way we can inherit the default Textbox settings?

Comment: That's described in the last paragraph of my answer :-) . Do you need more help with that?

Comment: No, I mean I don't want to copy and paste the default template, I just want to use some keyword to inherit the default settings.

Comment: No, unfortunately that is not possible, you must copy and edit it, as the `Template` value itself is just a visual hierarchy, so it would essentially not be possible to define any inheritance operation above it. It is multiple controls which have no "inheritable" properties.